# Assertion failure in -[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318/UIColor.m

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  UIColor *navBarColor =
  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SandPattern.jpg"]];

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:navBarColor];
    }
        else {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:navBarColor];
        }
        // various functions....
        return YES;
}
```

The app crash and throw the following error.

*** Assertion failure in `-[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318/UIColor.m:1448`

*** Assertion failure in `-[UICGColor encodeWithCoder:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318/UIColor.m:1448`

`libc++abi.dylib`: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code to update the navigation bar to a function and called it after others function in AppDelegate.m and it worked fine. Still looking for the exact logic behind the crash.

```
-(void)updateUI{
    UIColor *navBarColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SandPattern.jpg"]];
    //    [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:navBarColor ];
    }
    else {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: navBarColor];
    }
}
```

Final Code like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.

         // various functions....
           [self updateUI];
            return YES; 
 }
```